# Integrating lambda with IBM tone_chat error

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, ibm-watson, tone-analyzer

I'm trying to integrate my lambda function with IBM Tone_chat sentiment analyzer.
I'm getting an error of:

"errorMessage": "The first argument must be one of type string or Buffer. Received type undefined"

here is my event:

```
{ "utterances": [
        {"text": "Hello, can you help me", "user": "customer"},
        {"text": "How are you ?", "user": "agent"},
        {"text": "Nothing is working", "user": "customer"},
        {"text": "Sorry to hear this", "user": "agent"}
    ]}
```

If I change the event to:

```
{"text":"hello, this is test test, Happy sad"}
```

I get an error of: "{\"code\":400,\"sub_code\":\"C00012\",\"error\":\"Invalid JSON input at line 1, column 2\"}"

Here is my code:

```
            const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
            var http = require('https');
            exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
                    var text = event.text;
                    var options = {
                           method: process.env.method,
                           hostname: process.env.watson_hostname,
                           port: null,
                           path: process.env.path,
                           headers: {
                               'content-type': process.env.content_type,
                                authorization: process.env.authorization,
                               'cache-control': process.env.cache_control,
                               'X-Watson-Learning-Opt-Out': 'true'
                           }
                     };
                       var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
                       var chunks = [];
                       res.on("data", function (chunk) {
                       chunks.push(chunk);
                          });
                    res.on("end", function () { 
                           var sentimentResponse = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(chunks));
                       console.log("Sent respose");
                        callback(null, JSON.stringify(sentimentResponse));
                   });
                   })
      req.write(text);
      req.end()
        }
```

Can anyone please help me, I'm new to this, and I'm stuck on this for a while now!

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps you should do as the error says?

Comment: @Luuklag  do u have an idea how to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a little surprised that you are not getting the same error for both inputs, as you are not actually passing in `event`, `event.text` nor `text` in to the http request. How you do it really depends on whether you are using a `POST` or a `GET`.

If I was to give a recommendation it would be as a `POST` where you would add `text` as part of the request `body`.

> > Amendment to answer :
> >     After your update it looks like you are using a `POST`. in which case you need to stringify the json. So if `event.text` is your json object -

```js
let text = JSON.stringify(event.text);
```

For Usage see the API documentation - https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/tone-analyzer#analyze-general-tone

Comment: @ chughts Thanks for replying, I'm passing the event in my original code, I just missed to include it here, I've edited the code now.

Comment: So that needs to be a `POST` and the json needs to be `stringify` ed. Answer has been amended,